# Is there any in JSF2 a callback for activation / deactivation of a session bean?

Tags: jsf, listener, cdi, destroy, session-scope

I want to implement a callback for a session scoped bean in JSF2 / CDI, if the bean has been activated or deactivated by the container.

These methods I want to use it to start the transaction in the EJB.
The EJB itself is stateful, bean-managed with an extende Transaction Context.

There is a callback (PostConstruct), which is called after the creation of the bean from the CDI container.

My Bean looks something like this:

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

  @EJB private MyEJB myEJB;

  public MyBean () {
    super ();
    // do someting more (or not)
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init () {
    // do something for init ...
  }

  public void businessMethod () {
    // ..
  }
}
```

The @PostConstruct method is called only once at the beginning of the life cycle.

I want to be informed by the container when the bean is (re)activated at request startup or the bean is "parked" at the request end.

I think @PreDestroy is not the solution here.

Thank you for the help.

With best regards
Ronald

Comment: `@PreDestroy`? https://www.google.com/search?q=cdi+bean+session+deactivation+callback

Comment: @Kukeltje: I do not want to be informed about the life cycle of an EJB (@PostActivate, @PreDestroy), but when the container wakeup a JSF bean. But maybe that's a possibility.

Or have JSF Beans no life cycle?

Comment: 'waking up' meaning? You tagged the question with destroy and cdi and session-scoped, that is what I used in the query in google and @PreDestroy on a CDI bean seems suitable for that (and I did not mention EJB anywhere...). Your clarification helps, but it is now not a duplicate of what it was duplicated as... So you mean something like @PrePassivate/@PostActivate that exists for EJB's? There is no such thing as they are not in pools and not 'parked' and/or woken up at all... What is the actual usecase?

Comment: ok, the 'destroy' tag was not by you, and added after my comment, but that was actually what I thought was meant... I can reopen the question, but please clarify first

Comment: @Kukeltje: Ok, I have a JSF-Bean (SessionScope) with a reference to one or more EJB's (all are stateful, bean-manged with a extended persistencecontext). I want to be informed by the container when my JSF bean is activated in a request and deactivated at the end of the request. The fundamental question is thus a JSFBean has a life cycle, such as an EJB has a lifecycle. If so, is there a way to plug into this life cycle, as is possible with EJBs. If not, I have to look for another way.

Comment: You have a **CDI** managed bean, not a JSF managed bean (you use the `@Named` annotation, not `@ManagedBean`). And yes they have a lifecycle as you already know due to the `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations.  But they are not pooled like EJB's so there is no 'activation' or 'deactivation' at each request. A sessionbean is used if one of its methods are called, that's it. But please state the real usecase (non-technical)... Why do you need this? You are the first one to ask this, so I think this is an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Kukeltje: Ok, you're right. Not JSF but CDI managed bean. And CDI beans are not pooled, such as EJB's. With 'activation' I meant the time in the request processing to which the CDI is bean retrieved from the HTTP session. At the first request that is the call PostConstruct. But I think I made a mistake here. Basically I am looking for an idea of how I know within a CDI bean, at what stage of the (JSF) request handling my current location. Making the CDI bean to PhaseListener is a very bad idea because at the time at which the PhaseListener be instantiated, no EJB be injected.

Comment: You can retreive the current phase from the `FacesContext`…  but still, what is the usecase

Comment: @Kukeltje: Thanks for the note with the `FacesContext`. I had an idea that would allow me the annoying lazy initialization exception rid. The Application is what older and has some really bad design flaw. Has terribly large object networks. Object_a referenzeirt a list of object_b instances that can reference (as a list) again Objekt_C instances. In the client I need the entire object tree / network in the rarest cases. That's cruel.